# Using adb install option "-r" doesn't go through application.onCreate()

Tags: android, adb

I am trying to simulate an upgrade using the adb install option "-r" but starting the app after that doesn't go through Application.onCreate(). Here are steps I used to simulate the upgrade.

- adb install myapk
- running the app goes through application.onCreate() and app starts normally
- run the app again, it goes through application.onCreate() and app starts normally
- Now I increase my app's version code and name by 1. To simulate an upgrade, I used the command "adb install -r myapk".
- Now I run the app again but it doesn't go through application.onCreate() and the app starts normally.

Does any one know if its the expected behavior?

Comment: What does it do instead?  Does it fail with an error in logcat?  Does it resume without executing onCreate(), indicating that the old version has never been replaced by the new?   Do the signatures match? What did you do to start the app after the reinstall?

Comment: The app starts normally. Do you think it is getting cached.

Comment: If it starts normally without onCreate() then you probably haven't managed to change the installed version.  Watching logcat during the install attempt, or having each version of your app print or log something unique to identify it's version would be the way to know for sure.

Comment: The version was upgraded, I was printing it out to logcat.

Comment: Then assuming you implemented an onCreate() method, it went through that, regardless if you noticed that fact or not.  Otherwise you would just be resuming an old instance of the old version in an old process, something that a new version just cannot do.